# Show the W1 is a subspace of R4

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I must prove that W1 is a subspace of $R^4$. I am hoping that someone can confirm what I have done so far or lead me in the right direction.

$ W_1 = {(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \in R^4 | 2a_1 - a_2 - 3a_3 = 0 }$

From what I understand, I must show that: 
i) The zero vector of $R^4$ is in $W_1$
ii) Sum of any 2 vectors in $W_1$ must also be in $W_1$
iii) any scalar multiple of any vector in $W_1$ must also be in $W_1$

to show i), I just plugged in:
$ 2(0) - (0) - 3(0) = 0 $ therefore we have shown the zero vector is in $W_1$.

for ii), This is what I tried, and I'm not sure if it's correct:
Let $w_1$ and $w_2$ $\in W_1$.

Then I must show that $w_1+w_2 \in W_1$. What I wrote is that since we know by definition of $W_1$ that $w_1 = 0$ and $w_2 = 0$, then $0+0 \in W_1$. Does that prove that $W_1$ is closed under vector addition? If it is I will do something similar for iii), just want to see if I'm on the right track.

Thanks

Comment: But you don't have $w_1 = 0$ just because $w_1\in W_1$.

Comment: isn't it since W1 is 2a1-a2-3a3 = 0? so any vector in W1 is equal to 0? or is that false and im lost
edit: I see what you're saying, these proofs are a little bit confusing to me. What should I have written instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show ii:

write $w_1 = (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ and $w_2 = (b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$.  We have
$$
w_1 + w_2 = (a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,a_3+b_3,a_4+b_4)
$$
Now, you need to check whether, given $w_1,w_2 \in W_1$, we have
$$
2(a_1 + b_1) - (a_2 + b_2) - 3(a_3 + b_3) = 0
$$
Note that we can rewrite the above expression as 
$$
2(a_1 + b_1) - (a_2 + b_2) - 3(a_3 + b_3) = 
(2a_1 - a_2 - 3a_3) + (2b_1 - b_2 - 3b_3)
$$

Comment: thanks, this is what I needed